# Applying CSS to the LinkButton in hover

Tags: css

I have a Linkbutton in tag ul. I set css for ul. I want set forecolor for Linkbutton when hover

```
.MainMenu
{
position: absolute;
top:135px;
left:15px;    
background-color: #033E6B;
color:White;
border-style:double;
border-color:White;
}

.MainMenu li
{
float:right;
}

.MainMenu li a
{
color:Black;
}

.MainMenu li a:hover
{
color:Red;
}

 <ul class="MainMenu">
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
     <li><asp:LinkButton id="lnk" runat="server" PostBackUrl="Default.aspx">Home</a>   </li>
 </ul>
```

I use this code, it is work for tag a, but don't work for LinkButton!!

Comment: What does the final rendered HTML code, in the browser, look like?

Comment: change color for tag a when mouse over , but don't change for LinkButton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in the markup, change this `<asp:LinkButton id="lnk" runat="server" PostBackUrl="Default.aspx">Home</a>` to this `<asp:LinkButton id="lnk" runat="server" PostBackUrl="Default.aspx" Text="Home" />`

Comment: @ar.gorgin - I see you edited your question, but the error in markup is still there...

Comment: @NikolaBogdanović: It appears your solution is correct. Best to keep the erroneous original code in the question so anyone searching for a similar issue later will see the "Before" (Question) and "After" (Your Solution) examples.

Comment: @Lucanos - he edited his comment while i was responding, originally it stated that it did not work...

Answer (score 2):

There's an error in your code use the following markup for the `LinkButton`:

```
<asp:LinkButton 
    id="lnk"
    runat="server" 
    PostBackUrl="Default.aspx" 
    Text="Home">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

And remember to close your `<ul>` tag.

Hope it helps!